# JQuery Animate() showing sticky behaviour with other elements in the same class

Tags: jquery, css, web

for some reason all the `.inner-card` elements show some kind of animation, it is as if they are all erratically calculating their positions, instead of just the one element with the mouse hovering over it being animated cleanly.
any idea how can i fix this ?

[Link to Code](https://jsfiddle.net/ojw5dp6p/)

HTML:

```
    <div id="say-block">

        <div class="outer-card">
            <div class="inner-card">1</div>
        </div>

        <div class="outer-card">
            <div class="inner-card">2</div>
        </div>

        <div class="outer-card">
            <div class="inner-card">3</div>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
```

This is CSS

```
#say-block{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 1em;
    height: 4em;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 3em;
    background-color: #B7E4DF;
    padding: 1em;
    background-image: none;
    border-radius: 0.2em;
}

.outer-card{
    border:solid;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 1em;
    background-image: none;
    border-radius: 0.2em;
}

.inner-card{
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #680148;
    background-image: none;
}
```

This is .JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.inner-card').mouseenter(function() {
       $(this).animate({
        height: "+=0.5em"
     },
     500,
     'linear'
     );
   });
   $('.inner-card').mouseleave(function() {
       $(this).animate({
           height: "-=0.5em"
       },
       500,
       'linear'
       ); 
   }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `vertical-align: top` to the `.outer-card` css class.

This works because `.outer-class` is `display:inline-block` and the `vertical-align`property applies to inline elements.

[Code Example](https://jsfiddle.net/oyvn6136/)

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's because of the `display: inline-block` property on your `.outer-card` elements.

A work around for it is to use, `float:left` instead.

So what I did was update the block of css code of `.outer-card` to this :

```
.outer-card{
    border:solid;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    width: 1em;
    background-image: none;
    border-radius: 0.2em;
    margin: 0 6px;
}
```

Working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hLdd0uxj/3/)